# On Ocean Girl, does Neri fall in love with Jason?

Tags: ocean-girl

Can some one tell me whether Jason & Neri fall in love, and if so, in which series, on *Ocean Girl*...and do they have a relationship between them?

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing a second question into this one. It's the [Ask Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link in the top right of the page. If the text at the top left says "Science Fiction & Fantasy," you're in the right place. If it says "Science Fiction & Fantasy **meta**", you got off track somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, and in Series 4

To be specific, in the last episode, S04E26, Neri and Jason share, according to the wiki, a "[kiss of true love](http://ocean-girl.wikia.com/wiki/Neri)."
[image]

Here they are, about to kiss.

Yes, I would say that Neri fell in love with Jason.