# In Ocean Girl 3rd Series, did Jason have a secret crush on Neri?

Tags: ocean-girl

In *Ocean Girl*, 3rd Series 14th Episode, Jason said to Neri:

> You can be so stubborn. I was trying to protect you. You’re important to me, okay? To all of us, to the mission.

So can anyone tell me: does Jason mean he's in love with Neri, or only friendship?

[image]

Comment: Didn't I establish that Neri and Jason fell in love in my previous answer?

Comment: Jonah i m asking about 3rd Sirius  of Ocean girl..  is it Jason Had a secret Crush on Neri & is this known by Neri..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason certainly did have a crush on Neri. One piece of evidence is that, shortly thereafter, Neri and Jason shared a passionate kiss, as [indicated in my other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125330/on-ocean-girl-does-neri-fall-in-love-with-jason).

Jason probably was trying to conceal it, though, as indicated in your quote.

> You can be so stubborn. I was trying to protect you. You’re important
>   to me, okay? To all of us, to the mission.

Jason first admits that Neri is important to him, then backtracks and frames his concern in terms of her importance to the mission.